# How to find index of whole word in string in java

Tags: java, string, indexof, lastindexof

I want to find out all starting  indexes of whole word in a given string.
Lets say I have a string given below.

> "an ancient manuscripts, another means to divide sentences into
>   paragraphs was a line break (newline) followed by an initial at the
>   beginning of the next paragraph. An initial is an oversize capital
>   letter, sometimes outdented beyond the margin of text. This style can
>   be seen, for example, in the original Old English manuscript of
>   Beowulf. Outdenting is still used in English typography, though not
>   commonly.[4] Modern English typography usually indicates a new
>   paragraph by indenting the first line"); "

I would like to find out the starting index of "paragraph" only. Which should not include "paragraphs", "paragraph.".

Can anyone give an idea how to do it in java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to do. It seems like you are looking for "paragraph ". Add space.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html - useful functions for the String class.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regexp with [word boundaries character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
String text = "an ancient manuscripts, another means to divide sentences into paragraphs was a line break (newline) followed by an initial at the beginning of the next paragraph. An initial is an oversize capital letter, sometimes outdented beyond the margin of text. This style can be seen, for example, in the original Old English manuscript of Beowulf. Outdenting is still used in English typography, though not commonly.[4] Modern English typography usually indicates a new paragraph by indenting the first line";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bparagraph\\b").matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matching at: " + m.start());
}
```

If you don't want "paragraph." ("paragraph" followed by a dot), you can try

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bparagraph($| )").matcher(text);
```

which means paragraph followed by a space or a end-of-line.

If the String you are looking for can include special characters (like "("), you can use [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) to escape it:

```
String mySearchString = "paragraph";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(mySearchString) + "($| )").matcher(text);
```

Comment: This is working for normal strings, but if my string is "(or" it failes with "Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 13

Comment: My searchstring may or may not contain ( or )

Comment: @RaviGodara You can use : `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote("paragraph") + "($| )").matcher(text);`

Comment: Lets make it little simple If my string is String text = "paragraph paragraphs paragraph. (paragraph paragraph)"; I am expecting only 0. and when I am searching for "(paragraph" I am expecting index of "(paragraph" only. Thanks.

Comment: @RaviGodara Try that: `String mySearchString = "(paragraph"; Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(^| )" + Pattern.quote(mySearchString) + "($| )").matcher(text);`